# n.getFullYear is not a function error in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have the following code which is throwing
n.getFullYear is not a function error, 
any idea?

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([d3.time.sunday(d3.min(items, function(d) { return d.start; })),
        d3.max(items, function(d) { return d.end; })])
        .range([0, width]);



 "items": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "lane": 0,
        "start": "Mon Jan 16 2012 08:00:00 GMT+0545 (NPT)",
        "end": "Mon Jan 29 2012 08:00:00 GMT+0545 (NPT)",
        "class": "past",
        "desc": "This is a description."
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Show `items`, please.

Comment: edited, added items array

Comment: You have strings for `start` and `end`; d3 expects `Date` objects. Change `d.start` to `Date.parse(d.start)` (same for `d.end`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change d.start and d.end to return date objects
d3.time.scale().domain([d3.time.sunday(d3.min(items, function(d) { return new Date(d.start); })),
        d3.max(items, function(d) { return new Date(d.end); })])
        .range([0, width]);